# HTML5 has new tags article, section and aside. When should I use div tag?

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I understand the use of article, section and aside tags on HTML5. In many ways, these tags seem to replace div tag we use on HTML/XHTML. Well, div tag is continued on HTML5 too. Where and when can I use div tag for more semantic markup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<div>` element has **no** semantic meaning whatsoever. You can safely use `<div>` at any point where none of the semantically meaningful elements make sense.

A common example is a page layout wrapper `<div id="wrapper">`, whose sole purpose is to provide a visual wrapper for you to apply certain styles to.

Comment: Ok. That means the frequency of use of div tag will reduce, while being as important as on HTML/XHTML. This makes sense. Thanks :)